# Proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $p-2$ is not prime.

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Just need verification of this proof by contradiction:

Let $p_k$ be the largest prime number such that $p_k-2$ is not a prime number. Let $p_l$ be some prime number such that $p_l > 3p_k$. We know that $p_l$ exists because there are infinitely many prime numbers as proven elsewhere.

$p_l-2$ is a prime number. $p_l-4$ is a prime number as well. By induction, all numbers $p_k < x < p_l | x \mod 2 = 1 $ are prime numbers. But $p_k<3p_k<p_l$ and $3p_k \mod 2 = 1$ and $3|3p_k$ so there is a contradiction.

Also would love to see more concise proofs if at all possible.

Edit:

Great that I got so many people trying to provide their own proof but the question was primarily asked so that I could have my proof verified. Only skyking addressed my question, though I do not yet understand his criticism.

Comment: How about a proof by counterexample: $23-2=21$ not a prime?

Comment: @Aniket One is not very far on the way to proving infinitely many.

Comment: Since one of $p_t, p_t-2, p_t-4$ must be a multiple of $3$, it should suffice to take $p_t>p_k+4$. Anyway, I think your proof method (using only the infinitude of prime and not Dirichlet) is best

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: And an careful observation would reveal that it is not even a counterexample!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all some criticism, the proof seem to be somewhat overly complicated. But I see no fault in it.

It's not that clear that $p_l-4$ is a prime number, not using the fact that $p_k$ being the largest prime such that $p_k-2$ is not a prime at least.

The statement however follows quite easily from two observations:

1. There are infinite number of primes
2. There are infinite number of odd composite numbers (non-primes)

For each odd composite number $k$ there exists a smallest prime $p(k)>k$. Now since it's the smallest such prime you have that $p(k)-2$ is not a prime ($p(k)-2\ge k$, either it's $k$ and composite or between $k$ and $p(k)$ and therefore composite).

The first observation is a direct consequence of that $3(2n+1)$ is composite. The second is because otherwise (if there were finitely many primes) the product of all primes plus 1 would be another prime.

Comment: Thanks for actually addressing my proof at all. However I don't understand your criticism. If a prime $p$ is larger than $p_k$ it should obey the property that $p−2$ is a prime, no? So it seems to me that this implies that all odd number between $p_k$ and $p_l$ are primes

Comment: @DaBamti I missed the different indices, but you're correct. The real criticism should be that it's somewhat overly complicated.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple to construct such infinite sequence:

$$35+60n,37+60n$$

$35+60n$ will generate an infinite amount of composite numbers, all of which are divisible by $5$ (in fact, it will generate **only** composite numbers).

$37+60n$ will generate an infinite amount of prime numbers, since $37$ and $60$ are coprime integers (according to [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)).

Comment: That could be boiled down a lot: There are infinitely many primes $\equiv -1\pmod 6$ and for these $p-2$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Off course, using the fact that there are infinitely many primes $\equiv-1\pmod6$, it is much more obvious. But this fact is not so obvious by itself.

Comment: +1 for an easy answer avoiding the temptation to use Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions

Comment: @PVanchinathan: I take it you're being slightly cynical?

Comment: @barak manos: I am sorry if it sounded like that. I was trying to give an answer using Dirichlet's theorem and seeing $35+60n$ I stopped and decided to admire your answer. Once again, let me emphasize I like your answer very much(If you see some of the answers I have given, I try to give simple ones and also answers using words without needing LaTeX).

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Thanks, I appreciate it :) ... Though, I must say that you have yet again described it in a slightly cynical manner, by mentioning my numerical answer while stating that you prefer answers using words without needing LaTeX :)

Comment: Maybe I am dense, but this answer to me manifestly does use Dirichlet. Plus, I do not see why using it for 37 mod 60 is preferable to -1 mod 6 for instance.

Comment: @quid: 1. Where does the question say **not** to use Dirichlet? 2. Where did I say that using it for 37 mod 60 is preferable to -1 mod 6? 3. Please read my reply to the first comment here. Of course the "$-1\pmod6$" method is simpler, but I'm not sure how to show that there are infinitely many such prime numbers to begin with.

Comment: re 1. It does not say so anywhere, but a comment says "+1 for an easy answer avoiding the temptation to use Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions" This comment makes no sense to me as the answer does not avoid it. 2. I inferred that from your reply "But this fact is not so obvious by itself." It is not obvious for 37 mod 60 either. re 3. With Dirichlet's theorem (as -1 is coprime to 6, or of you do not like the negative number note it is the same as 5 mod 6). That's the point. You use it either way.

Comment: @quid: Yes, I agree, please read my comment right below that "+1" comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the simple fact that the numbers $n$, $n+2$, $n+4$ are all incongruent mod $3$, so that at least one of them must be a multiple of $3$. Thus the only triple of numbers $(n,n+2,n+4)$ consisting of all primes is $(3,5,7)$.

If $p_k$ denotes the $k^{th}$ prime and $k$ is the largest index for which $p_k - 2$ is not prime, then $p_{k+2} - 2 = p_{k+1}$ and $p_{k+1} - 2 = p_k$. Thus $(p_k,p_k+2,p_k+4)$ is a triple of primes, implying $p_k = 3$, which is an obvious contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if a prime $p>5$ is of the form $3n+2$ then $p-2$ is not prime.

There are infinitely many primes of the form $3n+2$.  This follows at once from Dirichlet's Theorem, but it can be shown directly (Pf:  were the list finite we could list all the examples, $\{p_1, \dots, p_k\}$ but then $P=3*\prod {p_i}-1$ is prime to everything on our list and is clearly not the product of primes of the form $3n+1$.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider multiples of $3$, and add $2$ in them. By Dirichlet's theorem, there are infinitely many primes in $\{ 3n+2\}_n$, and collecting them, subtract $2$ from them, we get non-primes.

Comment: Dirichlet seems like overkill for such a trivial theorem. it certainly works, but...

Answer (score -3):

We can have the obvious case where the last digit of *p* is 7. By drichlet's theorem on arthmetic progressions, we can generate a sequence of 5*n* + 7, where there are infinitely many primes with last digit as 7

Note: I considered the obvious case since (10k+7)-2 is divisible by 5, thus not prime