# Proof that there are infinite primes $p$ such that $p+2$ is not prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p\in\mathbb N$ be a prime. I want to prove that there is an infinite amount of primes $p$ with the property $p+2$ is not a prime. I am stuck on how to do this, though. I have tried an alternation of Euclids proof of the infinitude of primes but I cannot seem to find a construction that implies the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524092/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-p-such-that-p-2-is-not-prime) is a very similar question. You can apply the same method to your one and observe the steps that they use.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have found that page myself before, but the proofs there (stated the way they are) do not fully make sense to me. I was hoping someone could give a different proof or a differently worded proof from those on that page, fitting my specific problem.

Comment: The problem on that page is exactly the same as yours. The top two rated answers could hardly be simpler. What doesn't make sense to you about them?

Comment: I don't really know, sometimes I just can't understand a proof if it is formulated in a certain way. Anyway, the page that my answer was a duplicate to contained an answer that made perfect sense to me. Thank you all for your help!